# Global SE reputation page broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

My global stack exchange [reputation page](https://stackexchange.com/users/8d0ec064-29d6-4fe8-9114-78f03c6d446d?tab=reputation) gives me panda errors when I try to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed. Your >200 rep on the Atheism site, which no longer exists, was triggering the bug.

Comment: I don't *believe* that site exists. SEE WHAT I DID THERE? OMG.